# How can add lightbox to php link image

Tags: php, lightbox2

what is the right way to apply lightbox to this php code?

```
$output_content.=  "<div id=\"slide\" class=\"4u 6u(medium)\"><a href=\"$script_url/$cam_dir$prefix$k.$ext\">
    <img border=\"0\" src=\"$image_url_path/$prefix$k-thm.$ext?dontcache=".time()."\" alt=\"$cam_title - $timestat\" title=\" $cam_title - $timestat \" /></a><br />
    <small>$timestat</small></div>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by `right way`? Are you getting a PHP error? Does the lightbox just not activate?

Comment: i don't know where to put the lightbox code in the php code

Comment: Should be the same as the normal location.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the lightbox class or the class that fires lightbox to the `div class=` or `div id=`.

This is not a php issue I think it is a html issue.

Comment: I think that lightbox requires jquery, make sure that jquery is loaded in the head before lightbox. Make sure that you are then activating lightbox on that div. If the div is not correct, check the page -> inspect element -> check the class that is loaded -> insure your script is doing the sam.